# MFA on a new device

Tags: heroku

I had setup an MFA and after changing a phone I do not have access to the authenticator app and not able to log into my account.
When I try to log into the account it asks me for the authentication code. However, on a new phone I don't have access to the app I used on the old phone and I do not even remember what phone I used. I cannot talk to the support because it requires me to login. Please advice

Comment: We can't help you log in to arbitrary third party sites, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is not about login into authenticator app, it is about restoring or resetting mfa in heroku

Comment: Heroku _is_ that arbitrary third party site. SO isn't their support desk, we can't help you do that.